# lein-autodoc with Leiningen 2

Tags: clojure, leiningen, autodoc

I am attempting to use [lein-autodoc](https://github.com/tomfaulhaber/lein-autodoc), because I believe it to be the preferred documentation generator for Clojure. I have added `:dev-dependencies [[lein-autodoc "0.9.0"]]` to my project definition as per the instructions on the lein-autodoc github page.

Running `lein deps` runs without issue, however `lein autodoc` fails, claiming that autodoc is not a task.

I suspect the issue is that lein-autodoc is set up to work with leiningen 1. However, I'm using leiningen 2. Is there an alternate way I should be calling lein with autodoc? Or is the lein-autodoc package not set up to work with lein 2? If not, is there another preferred lein2-compatible documentation generation option?

**EDIT:**

After Cubic's hint below, I created `~/.lein/profiles.clj` as follows:

```
{:user {:plugins [[lein-autodoc "0.9.0"]]}}
```

Now, running `lein autodoc` results in the following:

```
$ lein autodoc
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: sh does not exist
    at clojure.core$refer.doInvoke(core.clj:3778)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5279)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5298)
    (...)
```

This suggests perhaps autodoc is not compatible with Lein 2? If not, is there any doc system that works with Lein 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

autodoc used to be the more common documentation generator, but these days it is mostly just used for Clojure itself (and is optimized for the task). I highly recommend that you use [codox](http://github.com/weavejester/codox) instead. It is excellent. You can see it in action in one of my own projects [here](http://raynes.github.com/laser/)

(I know this has been said in the other answer, but for my answer to be complete I need to add it anyways)

Also, in leiningen 2 there is no `:dev-dependencies` key. Instead, there is a `:dev` profile. Take a look at the Leiningen profile documentation for more information. In this case, all you need to do is add a `:plugins` key to your project or global user profile with the plugins you want (like codox, autodoc, etc).

Comment: Excellent. I was suspicious of whether autodoc was the latest and greatest. Thank you for an opinionated answer with good examples.

Comment: I know its an old question, but I wanted to chime in and say Marginalia makes beautiful documentation.  Its not as formal as codox or autodoc, but I think it creates a very nice, literate style. https://github.com/gdeer81/marginalia

Comment: This issue still exists with this answer.  `clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: sh does not exist, compiling:(leiningen/autodoc.clj:1:1)`  Why was it accepted?

Comment: Well, for starters, because it was not factually incorrect. You need to use :plugins for this in leiningen 2. But yes, https://github.com/tomfaulhaber/lein-autodoc/blob/master/src/leiningen/autodoc.clj#L4 is the reason it is broken. I suggest you submit a pull request or just fork the project if you want to use it. Personally, I'd just use one of the newer tools that... ya know... works.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `:dev-dependencies` in lein 2, you'd have to do it with [profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md).

I'm not sure whether autodoc actually works with lein 2 though. Keep in mind that clojure and it's environment grows pretty fast, and there's lots of outdated information out there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I went ahead and created a profiles.clj file, which clearly has registered autodoc as a task--it's just not working. I've edited the question accordingly.